# How to chose a random word from a list with a condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a junior coder and I wanted to choose a random element from my list with a few conditions and only If the conditions match the randon word should be printed can you please suggest a code that would work in python 3.
here is the code

```
`import time
import random
wordbank = ["   the "   ,
"   of  "   ,
"   and "   ,
"   to  "   ,
"   a   "   ,
"   in  "   ,
"   that    "   ,
"   I   "   ,
"   was "   ,
"   he  "   ,
"   his "   ,
"   with    "   ,
"   is  "   ,
"   it  "   ,
"   for "   ,
"   as  "   ,
"   had "   ,
"   you "   ,
"   not "   ,
"   be  "   ,
"   on  "   ,
"   at  "   ,
"   by  "   ,
"   her "   ,
"   which   "   ,
"   have    "   ,
"   or  "   ,
"   from    "   ,
"   this    "   ,
"   but "   ]
print("hey this is the champion AI robot which no human can beat in 
playing word bank")
quasimodo = input("want to know how it is played y/n")
if quasimodo == "y" :
     print("so each player is going to start by saying a word and the 
other person is supposed to tell a word by the ending letter of the word 
and the loop continues untill one person cant tell a word in 20 secs")
print("lets play i mean how long can a human last in front of a computer")
print ("because of my kindness i will let you start prepare to lose")

    
while 7 < 8 :
    a = input()
    b = len(a)
    c = b + 1
    d = random.choice(wordbank)
    e = a[c]
    f = len(d)
    g = f + 1
    h = d[g]
```

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and their desired outputs as well. Since your question is just text, it becomes difficult to imagine and construct your query and a solution for it.

Comment: ok I will add some code but it is huge

Comment: If possible try to edit your question with just the necessary code, whatever is important directly to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

lst = ['a','b','c']
print(random.choice(lst))
```

(Use the random module to get random values instead of going through the long process of creating a randomizer)

Answer (score 0):

Then select a random item of the list you can use `yourlist[random.randint(0, yourlist.length - 1)]`

Then  you can do your checks on this element.

Random [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html).